# SQL Query Return All Date which is weekend from a table

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have a table which has a field called `Date` , contains a list of date, and now I want to return a table contains a list of Date which is weekend with SQL Query.

I am using Microsoft Access and so far I have tried DATEPART and WEEKDAY, but they can only check if a specified date is weekend or not, not a list of Date.

How can I do that? Thank You

Comment: Some sample data and expected result, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to explain what you need...

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php

- `DATEPART("w"` will give the weekday from 1 to 7.
- `vbMonday` will ensure that Monday is weekday 1.

=>

- Saturdays are weekday 6 and Sundays are weekday 7.

```
WHERE
    DATEPART("w", yourField, vbMonday) >= 6
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked exactly as I want, I will write down the proper full code as a mark `Select * from Table where DatePart("w", Field, 2) >=6`